# How to use Gradle Cobertura plugin with Grails 3

Tags: grails, cobertura

I am trying to integrate the Gradle Cobertura plugin with my Grails application, but i seem to stuck in how i can hookup the plugin with my grails test-app runs.

I added the needed dependencies to the build.gradle file. So how can i use the plugin in the Grails application?

Answer (score 1):

You can run Cobertura as Gradle Task as follows :

```
gradle cobertura
```

For more details on tasks provided by the Plugin, you may go through https://github.com/stevesaliman/gradle-cobertura-plugin/blob/master/usage.md